# laravel version based routing not working

Tags: php, routes, postman, laravel-8

I am trying to access function using namespace routing. I got a error like this

( "message": "Invalid route action: [App\Http\Controllers\App\Http\Livewire\Auth\Login].",)

but I am not access this login file

**here is my code**

```
Route::namespace('Api\v1')->prefix('v1')->group(function(){
    Route::get('dash', 'UserController@dashboard');
});
```

**here is my api calling**

[image]

**Here is my output screenshot**

[image]

Comment: 1. Your controller must be placed in namespace `Api/v1`; 2. Enable global namespace in `RouteServiceProvider`; 3. Your URL should be `/api/v1/dash`

Comment: yes already namespace created. and also api calling also  using like this **api/v1/dash** @Thanh Dao